# Display toggle on/off

Tags: display, power, mac-pro

Sleep mode seems to cause problems with my MacPro.  Is there a way to turn the monitor off and on?  In "System preferences/Display/options" I can select "Display Power Button" "turns the display on and off" but that does not work.  If there is a key board toggle, that might help.

Comment: What problems do you have with sleep mode?

Comment: More people have problems awaking from sleep with a retina MBP. https://discussions.apple.com/message/23715722

Comment: Buscar: Incessant, but random, between a week to five weeks leaving the MacPro and Screen on, but configured to sleep automatically, one or both of two things happen: Upon waking the computer...(1) popup asks if I wish to close down the computer.  Then answering any of the three options does not stop the popup from reappearing. (2) Screen brightness will not stay bright.  It automatically goes to minimum.  I have tried many things to fix this...I have given up.  Now, I just put the display to sleep, thanks to George Garside's answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up a hot corner to turn the display off without going to sleep. Go to System Preferences → Mission Control → Hot Corners and set one of the corners to Put Display To Sleep. Wake the display by pressing any key.

Comment: Indeed a handy way to setup your system. Keep in mind that your password settings are in effect ('System Preferences, Security & Privacy, General, Require password). I also use the opposite corner to 'Disable Screensaver' to keep the system awake.

Comment: Wonderful: But, is "Put Display To Sleep" going to save the display, cause it to not remain hot to the touch? I found the following comment in trying to discern "sleep" versus "screen saver" choices in the Hot Corners options: "Forget about screen savers. They are a thing of the past ...they are just a fancy animation that is a huge waste of power and creates a lot of heat for nothing. Don't ever use a screen saver...Put the display to sleep (ctrl+shift+eject for the immediate) if you don't need it or leave it on if you do need it."

Comment: @Albie Yes, Put Display To Sleep will turn the display off completely rather than run a screensaver.